# Change logic in second Activity depending on Spinner in first Activity

Tags: java, android

I've looked through a lot of the answers on here about how to send the answer from a spinner to another Activity, but none of them are working for me.

In my first activity, I want to see which position the spinner is in so I can change questions that will come up in my second activity accordingly. Here is the code for my setupSpinner() method

```
    private void setupSpinner() {
    // Create adapter for spinner. The list options are from the String array it will use
    // the spinner will use the default layout
    ArrayAdapter grammarSpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.array_grammar_options,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // Specify dropdown layout style - simple list view with 1 item per line
    grammarSpinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);

    //Apply the adapter to the spinner
    grammarChoiceSpinner.setAdapter(grammarSpinnerAdapter);

    grammarChoiceSpinner.setSelection(0,false);

    // Create the intent to send the position to journal activity
    grammarChoiceSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), JournalActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("selected", position);
            Log.d("in spinner selected", "position of spinner:" + position );
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        // Because AdapterView is an abstract class, onNothingSelected must be defined
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            mGrammar = 0;
        }
    });
}
```

I put the log message there to see what was going wrong, but that log message never even came up.

Here is my onCreate() method. I want the spinner selection to be saved so I can choose which questions to ask in the journal. I also want to select "go" to choose "journal" or "exercise," then go to the correct activity from there. I have not yet created an exercise activity and am only focusing on journal right now. However, as soon as I select a spinner option, I am automatically sent to the journal.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_opening);

    //find the spinner to read user input
    grammarChoiceSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    setupSpinner();

    //Set up the intent and OnClickLIstener for the button to go to journal or exercises
    final Button chooseGrammarButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.goButton);
    final Button journalButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.journal);
    final Button exercisesButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.exercises);

    // make the Go button disappear and the exercises or grammar button appear
    chooseGrammarButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    journalButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    exercisesButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    chooseGrammarButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            chooseGrammarButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            journalButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            exercisesButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });

    //Set button to go to the journal page
    Button goToJournal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.journal);
    goToJournal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), JournalActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }
    });

}
```

In my second activity, I want to call a different method depending on which spinner was selected. Right now, my code only includes the option for spinner position 1 because I wanted to get the logic right before adding all the others. This is the second activity.

```
        @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_journal);

//        nextPresentQuestionButton();

    //TODO: fix this so the spinner answer is recorded and the logic follows
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int selected = intent.getIntExtra("selected", 0);
    Bundle extras = intent.getBundleExtra("selected");

    if (extras != null) {
        selected = extras.getInt("selected");
    }
    if (selected == 1) {
        nextPresentQuestionButton();
    }

}
```

Thank you so much for the help. I've spent hours trying to figure this out and I just can't understand what's wrong.

Comment: "but that log message never even came up"  that's very strange. Did you select an item?

Comment: you meant you `onItemSelected` method doesn't call on spinner item selection?

Comment: did your code go to `JournalActivity`?

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 - it most likely did not because OP did not call startActivity() :) I just wanted to know first why the Listener is not triggered

Comment: The code you show here looks right. Be sure to call startActivity().

Comment: As for the logging, sometimes Android Studio filters out logs that it shouldn't. Turn off the filtering and search the entire logcat. Alternatively, use `adb logcat` on the command line.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice if I call startActivity() my code automatically goes to JournalActivity without me clicking any buttons as soon as the app opens

Comment: @Ang then you are doing it in the wrong place. Call it in the listener.

Comment: Please give a complete code example. You need to show the class and method which contains the code.

Comment: Rather than writing "This is in the onCreate method." just do `public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance)`.

Comment: @Ang You misunderstand. I am asking to give code which is valid Java. This means that you need a class and a method. I do not need to see all of your code because most of it is irrelevant to your question.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice okay, I've edited my question - please let me know if that is enough

Answer (score 1):

try the following: add `startActivity()`

```
@Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, JournalActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("selected", position);
            Log.d("in spinner selected", "position of spinner:" + position );
            startActivity(intent)
        }
```

Get the Selected value in new activity using:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
int selected  = intent.getIntExtra("selected", 0);
```

Comment: I tried this, but if I add startActivity(intent) my code automatically goes to my second activity (JournalActivity) without me pressing a button or anything

Comment: add `grammarChoiceSpinner.setSelection(0,false);` after setting the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

I switched my code to SharedPreferences and that is saving it. I'm still working on loading it into the other activity, but this option is working much better. Here is my code now.

```
  private void setupSpinner() {
    // Create adapter for spinner. The list options are from the String array it will use
    // the spinner will use the default layout
    final ArrayAdapter grammarSpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.array_grammar_options,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // Specify dropdown layout style - simple list view with 1 item per line
    grammarSpinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);

    //Apply the adapter to the spinner
    grammarChoiceSpinner.setAdapter(grammarSpinnerAdapter);

    //Create shared preferences to store the spinner selection
    SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences
            ("Selection", MODE_PRIVATE);

    editor = preferences.edit();

    // Create the intent to save the position
    grammarChoiceSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            //receive the string of the option and store it
            int grammarOptionPosition = grammarChoiceSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
            //put the string in the editor
            editor.putInt("grammarOption", grammarOptionPosition);
            editor.commit();
            //make a toast so the user knows if it's not "select"
            if (grammarOptionPosition != 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Choice saved.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        // Because AdapterView is an abstract class, onNothingSelected must be defined
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            mGrammar = 0;
        }
    });
}
```